# Combinations of radiobuttons status checks using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have four radio buttons. At different situations, all these buttons could go either visible or hidden (All possible combinations). I need to check this condition "if not hidden and either one is not checked (Also all possible combinations) do something" using JQuery.

```html
<input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa1" value="currentOa1">
<input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa2" value="currentOa2">
<input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa3" value="currentOa3">
<input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa4" value="currentOa4">
```

An example of two such possible conditions and check in JQuery as follows

```js
if ($("#currentOa1").is(":visible") && $("#currentOa2").is(":hidden") && $("#currentOa3").is(":hidden") && $("#currentOa4").is(":hidden") && $('#currentOa1').prop("checked", false)) {
  alert("Current OA1 is not checked");
} else if ($("#currentOa1").is(":visible") && $("#currentOa2").is(":visible") && $("#currentOa3").is(":hidden") && $("#currentOa4").is(":hidden") && $('#currentOa1').prop("checked", false) || $('#currentOa2').prop("checked", false)) {
  alert("Please select one of the radiobuttons");
}
```

If need to hard code like the above, its a lot of if else and many combinations. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: It would be good if you gave a little more background on why you need this because otherwise it's hard to tell what we can do to solve this issue

Comment: The radio buttons will go hidden or visible based on some conditions. Before submit the form, I want to do the form validation using JQuery. In order to submit the form correctly, I need to make sure user selected at least one of the visible radio buttons. In my situation, as i explained in the question, there are so many combinations

Comment: Ok, then all you want is to check all the visible radio buttons and see if at least one is checked?

Comment: yes. that is correct

Comment: Ok, I'll provide a solution

Comment: Thanks for the effort. There is an answer posted which suits my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some class for the radio buttons and check the selection, visibility using that class name.

Sample code is below:

```js
var testSelection = function() {
        if ($(".rbs:visible").length > 0) {
            if ($(".rbs:checked").length > 0) {
                var selectn = $(".rbs:checked").attr("value");
                alert(selectn + " is selected");
            } else {
                alert("Please select one of the radiobuttons");
            }
        } else {
            alert("All options are hidden");
        }

    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="radio" name="currentOa" class="rbs" id="currentOa1" value="currentOa1">
    <input type="radio" name="currentOa" class="rbs" id="currentOa2" value="currentOa2">
    <input type="radio" name="currentOa" class="rbs" id="currentOa3" value="currentOa3">
    <input type="radio" name="currentOa" class="rbs" id="currentOa4" value="currentOa4">
    <input type="button" onclick="testSelection()" value="Check">
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it will solve.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this one is much close to your example, as opposed to other answers. Base on your example you want:

> You want to specify which radio button is not checked **if there is
>   only one** radio button visible, other wise you want to show the
>   message **"Please select one of the radio buttons"**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#btn').on('click',function(){
    var checked  = $('[name="currentOa"]:visible').map(function() {
        return $(this);
    }).get();


   var message = '';
   if(checked.length > 0){
      if(checked.length === 1 && !(checked[0].is(':checked'))){
        message = checked[0].attr('id') + ' is not checked!';
      }else if(checked.length > 1){

        var checked_item = 0;

        for (var i in checked){
          if(checked[i].is(':checked')){
            checked_item+=1;
          }
        }

        if(!checked_item){
          message = 'Please select one of the radio buttons';
        }
      }
   }


   if(message){
    alert(message);
   }


  });
 
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa1" value="currentOa1" >
<input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa2" value="currentOa2" >
<input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa3" value="currentOa3" >
<input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa4" value="currentOa4" >


<button id="btn">Validate</button>
```

Comment: This code always showing to select one of the radio buttons no matter it is hidden or already checked

Comment: @Anu I modified it. Kindly check. Thanks

Comment: Its working. However, I got a more simple code. I upvote your answer though

Comment: No worries. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the elements like this:

```
$('input:radio').each(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    // your code here...
  } else {
    //  unchecked code here...
  }
});
```

you can google "jquery loop through input radio" for more examples.

Comment: The scenario I having is not this